# How to code logistic growth model in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, regression, logistic-regression

model of logistic growth `x_(n+1)=x_n*r*(1-x_n)`.

Growth rate `r=2,5;3,1;3,8`.

Now i should calculate `x_n` by using difference values of `r`. Every `x_n` and `x_(n+1)` must save and then to code should print coordinates `(x_n, x_(n+1)) ((x_1, x_2), (x_2, x_3), ...)` to coordination.

[image: OPs code to replace]

I have write some code but it doesn't work right and i can find the way to code that kind of program.

Comment: Would you please add some example data by editing your question? That would make helping you much easier.

Comment: including a screenshot is discouraged, please edit the question and copy and paste code directly in.  also what are those `r` values?  is that a Matlab formatted 3x2 matrix, or a vector of three numbers with commas for decimal place (note that Python uses `.` for the decimal place), or something else?

Comment: At first glance there's nothing wrong with your code. Which is the expected answer for that example that you posted? (0.2, 2.5, 2)

As they have already suggested, having the code writen so we can copy and paste quickly and having some example and expected value would help a lot :)